# jquery apply css to all elements except second row

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to move all rows data except second row using jquery. How do I achieve that?

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chandana2014/CrumK/68/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tblTest tr:nth-child(2) td").css("padding-left", "30px");  
    //$("#tblTest tr:not(nth-child(2)) td").css("padding-left", "30px");  

});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your attempt was close, you just missed the colon before `nth-child`:

```
$("#tblTest tr:not(:nth-child(2)) td").css("padding-left", "30px");
//-----------------^--This One
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CrumK/69/)

Comment: what is difference between .children and .td? which one is the best?

Comment: They are different things. But many `:` selectors have counter-part methods that do a similar thing. Except these methods filter the selection after it has been made. (Methods are often quicker!)

Answer (score 7):

You can use **[.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)**:

```
$("#tblTest tr").not(':eq(1)').children().css("padding-left", "30px");
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CrumK/70/)**

Answer (score 4):

use `.not()` with `.eq()`try this:

```
 $("#tblTest tr").not(':eq(1)').find("td").css("padding-left", "30px");
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CrumK/71/)**

Comment: @oGeez: Your comment worked, All downvotes are reverted. Just wondering how do people downvote without checking if the answer deserve it or not

Comment: @Karna:even when there is working fiddle in answers.

Comment: @oGeez Yah I did experience this many times http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171443/serial-negative-group-voting.

Comment: @oGeez:it happens almost every other day. People downvote for no reason. sometimes i used to delete such answer but later on ended with  same thing being right and accepted for other answer posted later on.